# I messed my layout somehow

Tags: modeling

I probably pressed something I did not want and now, my layout is missing typical background. I cant see my reference pictures and I cant see vertices in edit mode either. How to do I restore default settings?
Sorry for posting such a dumb question, but I cant finish my snowman like this. :(

[image]

Comment: See the blue icon, on top right with some kind of arc and arrow? Click on the one on its right, the one with two circles on it.

Comment: Thank you, lifesaver!